# HMR in asp.net core with React

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, webpack

I started my project using .net core cli.

```
dotnet new react -o my app
```

and for development, I changed my env var

```
export ASPNETCORE_Environment=Development
```

I am not very comfortable with Typescript so, I prefer use .jsx files and babel, so I decided to change my webpack.config.js. In module rules, I added:

```
const BABEL_LOADER_PLUGINS = [
  require.resolve("babel-plugin-transform-class-properties"),
  require.resolve("babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread"),
  require.resolve("babel-plugin-transform-regenerator")
];

/*...webpack config code ... */

{
      test: /\.jsx$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["env", "react"],
            plugins: BABEL_LOADER_PLUGINS
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

I did my new components with .jsx extensions and it works. So my next step is to do HMR work.
In my Startup.cs:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
            {
                HotModuleReplacement = true
            });
        }
```

In client at root component, using react-hot-loader':

```
let HotApp;
if (__CONFIGS__.isDevServer) {
  const { hot } = require('react-hot-loader');
  HotApp = hot(module)(App);
} else {
  HotApp = App;
}

const Root = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <HotApp />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);
```

hydrate(Root, document.getElementById('react-app'));

And this sometimes works. In the console, I can see [HMR] connected and updates. If I stop the process, it is possible that console shows [HMR] connected but if I do some changes in a component nothing happens. I don't know why sometimes works well.

Answer (score 0):

We can use [Create React App Configuration Override](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco) ([`@craco/craco`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco)) along with [`craco-plugin-react-hot-reload`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/craco-plugin-react-hot-reload) CRACO plugin to add HMR without ejecting the CRA application.

1. Install [`@craco/craco`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco) by following the [installation guide](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco/README.md#installation)
2. Install [`craco-plugin-react-hot-reload`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/craco-plugin-react-hot-reload)

   ```
   npm i -D craco-plugin-react-hot-reload
   ```
3. Add [`craco-plugin-react-hot-reload`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/craco-plugin-react-hot-reload) into `craco.config.js`

   ```
   const reactHotReloadPlugin = require('craco-plugin-react-hot-reload');

   module.exports = {
     plugins: [{
       plugin: reactHotReloadPlugin
     }],
     webpack: [...]
   }
   ```
4. Install [`@hot-loader/react-dom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hot-loader/react-dom)

   ```
   npm i @hot-loader/react-dom
   ```
5. Mark your `App` component as *hot-exported* (into `ClientApp\src\App.js`)

   ```
   import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root';

   function App() {...}

   export default hot(App);
   ```

Now HMR will work properly when we start the project using `dotnet run`.

Tested (*on May 2020*) using React `16.13.1`. We must use the same major and minor versions for `react`, `react-dom` and `@hot-loader/react-dom` (`16.13.x`).